# Xampp won't start apache and mysql

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

My Xampp control panel won't start apache and mysql. When I click start the control panel console stays frozen in this state:

> 16:27:46  [main] Initializing Control Panel
>
> 16:27:46  [main] Windows Version:  Home  64-bit
>
> 16:27:46  [main] XAMPP Version: 7.2.2
>
> 16:27:46  [main] Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
>
> 16:27:46  [main] Running with Administrator rights - good!
>
> 16:27:46  [main] XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\programmieren\datenbanken\xampp\"
>
> 16:27:46  [main] Checking for prerequisites
>
> 16:27:46  [main] All prerequisites found
>
> 16:27:46  [main] Initializing Modules
>
> 16:27:46  [Apache] Apache Service detected with wrong path
>
> 16:27:46  [Apache] Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
>
> 16:27:46  [Apache] Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>
> 16:27:46  [Apache] Found Path: "C:\programmieren\sql\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
>
> 16:27:46  [Apache] Expected Path: "c:\programmieren\datenbanken\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
>
> 16:27:46  [mysql] MySQL Service detected with wrong path
>
> 16:27:46  [mysql] Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
>
> 16:27:46  [mysql] Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>
> 16:27:46  [mysql] Found Path: C:\programmieren\sql\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\programmieren\sql\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini MySQL
>
> 16:27:46  [mysql] Expected Path: c:\programmieren\datenbanken\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\programmieren\datenbanken\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini MySQL
>
> 16:27:46  [main] Starting Check-Timer
>
> 16:27:46  [main] Control Panel Ready
>
> 16:27:49  [Apache] Attempting to start Apache service...
>
> 16:27:50  [mysql] Attempting to start MySQL service...

I'm running the control panel with administrator rights. I tried to reinstall Xampp, but it didn't help. I only have a single Xampp version installed. I don't have any clue what to do or what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](//superuser.com).

Comment: Also: Try WAMP instead.

Comment: Did you check your logs ? :) maybe its a port issue with skype :)